# is full background html5 video is supported in mobile device?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, video

I have used wordpress plugin called "Video Background" for integrating full background video to the website.But it is not playing in mobile device.Also it is not playing in Safari browser in dekstop.

I need suggestion of other plugin or method, by which i can play video on both mobile/desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://wphowto.net/videojs-html5-player-for-wordpress-757?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported on iOS I'm not sure about android but I don't think it's supported either. I would recommend using an animated gif. That's supported everywhere. Otherwise you'd have to script something.